# I can't perform database migrations. I'm using PostGreSQL. See the error it gives me:

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, product, django-migrations, alter-table

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "logistica_requisicao" violates foreign key constraint "logistica_requisicao_produtos_id_bc49525e_fk_produto_produto_id"
DETAIL:  Key (produtos_id)=(235) is not present in table "produto_produto"
```

I tried to make migrations but i could not.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, there is no way to tell what went wrong with just that message, if you could provide a E-R model/Schema/your models.py file it would be a lot easier to see what went wrong

Comment: The message is pretty clear, produtos_id 235 is missing in table produto_produto. Check this table and check your content.